# How do I get the selected option in a list?

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists

Let's say I have the following drop down list.

```
<select id="products">
    <option value="test1">Test1</option>
    <option value="test2">Test2</option>
</select>
```

I want to show specific `div`'s only when a specific option is selected. I know how to show and hide them, but I have no idea how to detect.

1. The selected option when the page is loaded, and
2. The selected option when a user selects something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. On document ready you just do $("#list option:selected").text(); or .val(); depending on what you need.

   ```
     $(document).ready(function() {   alert($("#products
     option:selected").text()); });
   ```
2. You can either bind a .change function to the list or you can have an onchange function inline in the html.

   ```
   $("#products").change(function() {
   alert($("#products
    option:selected").text()); 
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

this will get the selected values and store them in an array, last index of array is the newest value and previous values are selected before:

```
var valArr = [];
$("#products").change(function(){
    valArr.push($(this).val());
})

alert(valArr);
```